# Override contents of table layout at runtime

Tags: android

I have created a table layout in xml. At runtime, i am using a condition where in first case i am filling table layout. However in second case i am again adding contents to the same layout. And they get added up at the end of layout. However i need to clear the previous contents of layout i.e. of first case by contents of second case. 
Any suggestions ???

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you are looking for, but you can use these TableLayout's methods to remove tableRows as needed:

```
public void removeView (View view)
public void removeViewAt (int index)
public void removeViews (int start, int count)
```

refer to docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html (these methods are inherited from ViewGroup)